# How can I change between language in a single IME?

Tags: android, ime

I am trying to make a Korean IME, but I can't find a good example.

How can I change between languages in a single IME?

I mean, like in Apple's IME, which uses a globe icon to switch between languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways.  The first way is to just change the keyboard layout.  There's no rule that says the language on the keyboard has to match the onscreen language.  An example of this is Swype-  it allows you to chang the language of the keyboard without changing the language of the rest of the UI, useful for bilingual typers.  This is totally internal to your app, so you just need to track the keyboard language and show the correct key layout.

The other way is to set the phone's locale.  The disadvantage to this is that it will change the language used inside of the app, and all other apps.  To do this, use

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```